# Line of reasoning in the solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $(n-1)^2|n^k-1$ if and only if $n-1|k$

**Solution:** $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} n^{i} \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 1^{i} \equiv k \mod{n-1}$ So we need $k \equiv 0 \mod{n-1} $

Could someone explain to me the line of reasoning for thinking about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get $$\frac{n^k-1}{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n^i\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}1^i=k.$$ That is $$\frac{n^k-1}{n-1}$$ is divisible by $n-1$ if and only if $k$ is.